# Rails url project check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app that users can create projects.  One user cannot see the other user's projects.  However, if i copy the url of a project that user 1 created (e.g. `localhost:3000/projects/23/edit) and log into user 2 and paste the direct url, I can still edit the information.  What would be the best way to cross reference the user that created the project to only allow that user to see/edit the param linked page?

EDIT
In my projects controller I have:

```
def index
    @projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user)
    @default_working_project = current_user.default_working_prodject
    unless production.user == current_user
        redirect_to dashboard_index_path
end
```

Comment: Are you using Devise? It might be helpful to post the code in `projects#edit`. In any case, one solution would be to add a `before_action` that redirects anyone that isn't the owner of the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a foreign_key on the project (like owner_id, or user_id), then you can do

```
current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
```

in the projects controller to only get existing projects accessible by that user.

I suspect you have something in your database to identify users and their relationship to the project.

In the sql query a where clause is added: `projects.user_id = ?`.  Because of this, an exception will be thrown to any users that do not have access and a 404 not found will be raised.

Comment: Yes I have a master project list that uses `current_user.projects.find(params[:id])` to list the items, but what about users who type a link in manually?

Comment: Added a little more to the answer.  The unauthorized will get a 404

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up Authorization so you can control who is allowed to do what to any project.

There are several gems out there to help with this, I personally would recommend Pundit. https://github.com/elabs/pundit